# Взаимодействие function и querySelector.All

Tags: javascript, html, функции, queryselectorall

Не могу понять как работают вместе функции и выбор по всем селекторам в js. Ибо по логике должны выбраться все селекторы и они должны взаимодействовать функцией, но это так не работает, функция не работает.
Я сам ещё только учусь,наверняка именно поэтому не могу понять что здесь не так,но чувствую,что функцию написал неправильно.

```html
<body>
    <div class="modal_container">
        <div class="open_modal">
            <button class="open_modal_btn">Launch Modal</button>
        </div>
    <div class="modal-window">
        <div class="modal_header">
            <h1 class="modal_title">Modal title</h1>
            <button class="exit_btn js-close">
                <span class="btn_icon">X</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal_body">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero itaque similique ut, iure sit dolores, qui deserunt doloremque debitis perspiciatis voluptas quos accusamus adipisci repellat dicta alias ipsam ipsum a.</div>
        <div class="modal_footer">
            <button class="modal_footer_btn close_btn js-close">Close</button>
            <button class="modal_footer_btn save_btn js-close">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
/*let launch = document.querySelector('.open_modal_btn');
let modal = document.querySelector('.modal-window');
let container = document.querySelector('.modal_container');*/
let close = document.querySelectorAll('.js-close');

/* launch.onclick = function start() {
    modal.style.display='block';
    modal.classList.add('modal-window_open');
    modal.classList.remove('modal-window_close');
    container.style.backgroundColor='#4d4d4d';
    launch.style.display='none';
}; */
close.onclick = function end() {
    modal.classList.add('modal-window_close');
    modal.classList.remove('modal-window_open');
    container.style.backgroundColor='#fff';
    launch.style.display='block';
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.js-close').forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', function() {
  modal.classList.add('modal-window_close');
  modal.classList.remove('modal-window_open');
  container.style.backgroundColor='#fff';
  launch.style.display='block';
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

document.querySelectorAll() возвращает коллекцию нодов, поэтому по ней надо пробежаться:

```
close.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener(...);
});
```